# send email with php and html content

Tags: php, html, email, opencart, send

```
      <?php 
   $subject = $this->language->get('text_subject');
    $message = "este es el mensaje";
    $html = "<html><head><title>Documento sin título</title></head><table>
        <tr>
        <td>Ticket</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>action</td>
        <td>account type</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>COMPLETED</td>
        <td>CREATE</td>
        <td>DEMO</td>
        </tr>
        </table><body></body></html>"

                $mail = new Mail();
                $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
                $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
                $mail->hostname = $this->config->get('config_smtp_host');
                $mail->username = $this->config->get('config_smtp_username');
                $mail->password = $this->config->get('config_smtp_password');
                $mail->port = $this->config->get('config_smtp_port');
                $mail->timeout = $this->config->get('config_smtp_timeout');


                $mail->setTo($customer_query->row['email']);
                $mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
                $mail->setSender($this->config->get('config_name'));
                $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
                $mail->setHtml($html);
                $mail->setText(html_entity_decode($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));



                $mail->send();?>
```

I have this code to send email php,  `$html` contains code html to send mail, but only appears the html code and the text does not appear. there is an error in the code?

Comment: which class you r using for email. there must some option for setting HTMLemail to be sent. and $html i hope is defined in ur script somewhere

Comment: I've modified the code

Comment: The text body is set to $message, which is just "este es el mensaje" -- is that what you wanted to send?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to send

Comment: Take a look a this tutorial :) http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting both HTML and TXT messages to be sent. This means that both messages are sent and depending on your email client only one is displayed. If your email client can display HTML messages and this is turned on, only the HTML message is displayed, otherwise only the TXT message is displayed. The HTML and TXT messages **should not** contain different content but the same - one in HTML format and one as a plain TXT substitution for clients not supporting HTML format.

In this case, if you are sending HTML message like above, the TXT substitution should be

```
$message = "Documento sin título\r\n";
$message .= "Ticket:       1\r\n";
$message .= "Status:       COMPLETED\r\n";
$message .= "action:       CREATE\r\n";
$message .= "account type: DEMO\r\n";
```

Maybe what you need is to send two emails (and maybe to two different users?)...